# Computer Components Trivia Project, strange text file issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am stuck; my teacher and my classmates don't know how to help or why this is happening.

```
   total=0
questions=open('questions.txt','r')
for x in range(20):
    print(questions.readline())
    print(questions.readline())
    P1=input('Which answer is correct? type the corresponding letter: ')
    rightanswer=questions.readline()
    if P1==rightanswer:
            print('correct!')
            total=total+1
    if P1!=rightanswer:
            print('incorrect!')
```

So all of this works fine, the issue lies with the right answer. My layout for the text file is as follows:

```
What is hardware component in a computer that stores random information?
a: VrAM, b: GPU, c: CPU, d: RAM
d
```

It continues on in the text file with all the questions, (he expects 20). It always prints 'incorrect!', until the final question, where it actually detects that my answer is correct. I don't know how to fix this, it seems that my code is okay, because it does work, but only at the end of the text file is when it tells me that my answer is actually correct.

Comment: `print(repr(rightanswer))` - I'd guess you have a newline for every line in the file but the last.

Comment: Which answer is correct? type the corresponding letter: a
incorrect!
What holds all the components inside a computer?

a: CPU, b: RAM, c: Motherboard, d: Hard Drive

Which answer is correct? type the corresponding letter: c
correct! |||||||

this is the output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a homework completion service. Your instructor gave you the assignment, not us, and you're going to need to do your own work. If you can't get started, ask your teacher for help; they're being paid to teach you. If your teacher gave you an assignment they are unable to complete themselves, complain to your school's adminstration. Good luck.

Comment: okay, i didn't expect you guys to do any of my work for me, I was just hoping to find a solution to my problem, seeing as my teacher suggested I ask around for a solution anyway. Thanks to jonrsharpe's suggestion, i realized that it kept printing incorrect because each right answer had /n next to it, so it wasn't actually just the letter, it was the letter with /n. We can strip /n from the lines right?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is as @jonrsharpe mentioned. You can correct that by using the string method strip() which removes leading/trailing white space. So, two lines should be changed as :

```
P1=input('Which answer is correct? type the corresponding letter: ').strip()
rightanswer=questions.readline().strip()
```

Comment: that worked, thanks a lot everybody. sorry if it seemed like i wanted you guys to do my 'homework'.

Answer (score 0):

needed to strip \n from my lines so that it would actually register as the right answer.